# How can I list upnp server/renderer in command line (console mode) on linux?

Tags: linux, console, upnp, ssdp

I want to list my available upnp/dlna renderers on my local network in console mode.

I can do that with gupnp but not in console mode

Answer (score 59):

gssdp-discover (from gupnp-tools) will list devices and services advertized over SSDP:

```
gssdp-discover -i wlan0 --timeout=3
```

You can also specify the target (as uuid or a service/device type):

```
gssdp-discover -i wlan0  --timeout=3 --target=urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1
```

Comment: is there a windows version of this?