# What is the common way to discover physical servers in a datacentre?

Tags: hardware, ipmi, device-discovery

In a modern datacentre, it is said that after a physical server gets plugged into the switch, then it can be discovered and then registered to the datacentre inventory system automatically without human intervention, and later on the system can be provisioned by a default OS using PXE like technical, also automatically.

What is the common way of doing physical server auto discovery? The way I know a little bit is:

- Physical server management console (ILO) bootup automatically by querying IP address from the IDC DHCP server
- A management system sending broadcast ping to the whole network, any IP address which responds and has no record in the system is considered to be a new system.
- Management server connect to the server ILO using standard IPMI protocol and set the interface PXE configuration, then power cycle the server
- When server boot up, a PXE installation is processed. Server information can be registered to the inventory system during the installation procedure.

Is there any other good way of doing this?

Comment: find a good talk about this at https://github.com/spkane/velocityny_2014-automating_hardware

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path if you are using the iLO. iLO supports LLDP discovery. An additional option will be to manage it from the iLO RESTful API that is also Redfish conformance.

SSDP is certainly very common and popular for this purpose outside the datacenter. An example of performing such discovery can be found here:
[How can I list upnp server/renderer in command line (console mode) on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363833/how-can-i-list-upnp-server-renderer-in-command-line-console-mode-on-linux)

Which uses the gssdp-discover utility.

Redfish standard, which all major vendors support, specifies the

```
gssdp-discover -i eth0 --timeout=3 --target=urn:dmtf-org:service:redfish-rest:1
```

Ana- HPE Employee