# Discover Devices using SSDP Protocol

Tags: ssdp

I have a device that broadcasts a UDP message every couple of seconds. I would now like to listen for these messages. The way this works is like this:

1. I send a DISCOVER message to broadcast (255.255.255.255:1999)
2. The device in response sends me a response payload in the form of a UDP packet

This response message contains the IP address of the device, it's MAC address and many more information. Is there any tool that I could use to broadcast such a message?

I will be running this tool on a Linux hardware!

Comment: A) asking for tools and recommendations is usually not a good question for SO, B) you don't mention the language or platfofrm you are using or even the operating system. -- even if someone answers it's probably not going to be in the context you hoped for

Comment: I tried using Java Datagram, but I could not get that to work. So I thought of checking with SO if I could get some recommendations for some tools like Wireshark that would atleast enable me to make sure that the device is indeed responding to my broadcast message!

Comment: Okay, but you got my point right? There are dozens of developer tools that will allow you to send or receive SSDP messages and typically they have dependencies (linux, windows, Java, dotnet, whatever). Sure, I can point you to my answer to a similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363833/how-can-i-list-upnp-server-renderer-in-command-line-console-mode-on-linux/18366724#18366724 . If it turns out you are not on linux, then we have both wasted time, something you could have avoided by mentioning where this tool should run.

Comment: Shouldn't that be port 1900 and not 1999?